# Cannot read data from app.config in Windows 10 & asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, windows-10

I am working on a asp.net application that stores important data in app.config. In all Windows versions before Windows 10, the tests correctly load the data I want, but once I upgraded a system to Windows 10, the application no longer is able to pass the same test and fails to grab data. Whenever it read from the app.config file, as seen in the code below, Null is always returned.\

```
var data = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathName"];
```

When run in Windows 8, the value returned is a valid string that I use. When run in Windows 10, null is returned despite the file being present just as before. Once the value is used later on in regards to path3, an Exception is tripped and the error shown below occurs. Path3 comes from a function that the Null value is passed into.

```
threw exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path3
```

I have tried changing user permissions to files, folder and so on, but nothing seems to change this. I have also changed the User Account Control settings with no luck. I am using Visual Studios 2013 Professional and always run it in under admin mode.

Everything I have looked at online has not helped much and pretty much reiterates most of the steps I have already tried. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

**Contents of app.config (Key = "PathName")**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
 </configSections>
 <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PathName" value="DATA_VALUE_NEEDED" />
  </appSettings>
  <applicationSettings>
 </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: path3? where does this variable come from?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem with reading the .config file. "path3" seems to be null when being passed to some method, which a .config file doesn't do.

Comment: I should have clarified that. The variable data is used in another function that needs the correct file name being loaded. So, path3 is a variable down that line that uses the data variable. When the variable is used, the error is thrown. I'll update the question to clarify that.

Comment: On Windows 8, the value of data is a valid string that I need. On Windows 10, without changing a thing, the value of data is Null. How null is used is what trips the Exception.

Comment: show the config section or `["FileKey]"` please also show where the `var` data is being used elsewhere in the program

Comment: PathName in config but you search for a FileKey? Is this a typo?

Comment: The problem is that the value is coming back null, not where it is crashing so showing the latter code would not help. My problem is in the app.config not being able to be read on Windows 10 for some reason.

Comment: Yeah it is, the actual key is "PathName". I removed it from the original code so I will update that now.

Comment: u have mentioned that you tried changing user permissions. Still could you try giving "Everyone" Full Access to all the folders in the root, if you haven't tried that yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying a lot of solutions, I finally figured out what was creating the problem. I'm not exactly sure why this occurred, but this is what happened all the same.

On windows 8, the app.config file from test projects loads directly from the main project it is meant for. Meaning, if you create a separate project for your tests, it links to the original that it was created for when loading app.config files.

In Windows 10, this does not seem to be the case for some reason. For some reason, the app.config file being read in was not the one for the project the tests were created for. It was some sort of auto generated default despite no settings or configurations being changed between porting the code between the two OS versions.

I was able to solve the problem by copying the file directly from the main project into the test project for it. Then, with a link between the two, they will stay updated when either one is changed.

I still don't understand why this happened and cannot locate the generated app.config file. After debugging, I simply noticed that the loaded key value pairs available did not exist in any single XML files in the entire project repository. Hopefully this helps others down the road with the same problem since I have seen several other reports online of people running into what seems to be this problem. Thanks everybody for your help!